# How to enable boot from USB stick on ASUS k555la xo318h

Tags: boot, laptop, uefi, asus-laptop

I have a ASUS k555la xo318h laptop which is came with windows 8.1 and I want to install windows 7 on it.
For some reason it didn't let me to access the install menu, no matter which USB entrance I tried
(it has 1 - 2.0 port and 2 - 3.0 ports).
Even though I try to access it through the override menu or through the Esc key (just to boot directly to the desired drive) it shows me a black screen for a brief moment and then returns to the previous screen.
I know this is not a problem in my own USB because I checked it out already with several computers and worked great, and beyond that, the same phenomenon occurs even when I use different USB drives with different operating systems (for example hirens live-cd, the same happening).

---

I've tried to ask Google-Sensei about it but except for disable the secure boot recommendations (I've already disable it) I haven't not found anything relevant to the matter.
I'm currently using *BIOS 308* but I seriously doubt it will help to upgrade it, because the latest updates merely add (so far):

- Disable SATA Device Sleep.
- EC FW Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an CSM option in the "boot" menu which is changing the UEFI mode to the old boot mode.
After I enabled it, the USB is recognized without a sweat.